# create service account and assign permissions/roles at the organization level in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I need to fetch all the projects and associated resources details underneath an org in GCP. What is the best way to do this. Can i create a service account bound to an organization and what type  of roles need to be assigned to the Service account to control all type of resources under an organization.

Comment: You will need to compile a list of resources and bind IAM roles to an identity for those resources. As Google Cloud releases/updates services, you will need to update that IAM role binding list. No role grants permission to everything.

Answer (score 0):

The service account can be granted IAM roles that let it access resources. The service account is used as the identity of the application, and the service account's roles control which resources the application can access.

You can grant users permissions using [custom roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles). These roles operate on the principle of least privilege, and generally provide only the minimum necessary permissions required to do a particular task.Because of their restricted permissions, however, custom roles may cause many resources in your hierarchy to be [omitted](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/listing-all-resources#troubleshooting_omitted_resources) when executing a list operation. When performing searches as a user that has been granted a custom role, it can be difficult to tell why certain resources are not appearing.

To get the permissions that you need to create and manage custom roles, ask your administrator to grant you the following IAM roles:

- To manage roles for a project: Role Administrator (roles/iam.roleAdmin) on the project that you want to manage roles for
- To manage roles for an organization: Organization Role Administrator (roles/iam.organizationRoleAdmin) on the organization that you want to manage roles for.

As mentioned there is no single role that can be given to a service account to control all types of resources. If a user needs access to a specific Google Cloud resource, you can grant the user a role for that resource. Some examples of resources are [projects](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/cloud-platform-resource-hierarchy#projects), [Compute Engine instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances), and [Cloud Storage buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/buckets).

Some services support granting [IAM permissions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview#resource) at a granularity finer than the project level. For example, you can grant the Storage Admin role (roles/storage.admin) to a user for a particular Cloud Storage bucket, or you can grant the Compute Instance Admin role (roles/compute.instanceAdmin) to a user for a specific Compute Engine instance.

To list all the resources in the [resource hierarchy](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/listing-all-resources#list_all_resources), Grant a service account the list and get permissions for Organizations, Folders, and Projects on the Organization resource.

Comment: but my basic ask is, how to create a service account for an org and provide the SA appropriate accesses?

Answer (score -1):

1. Can i create a service account bound to an organization?

   Yes, you can bound a service account to an organization
2. What type of roles need to be assigned to the service account to control all type of resources under an organization.

   If you need to control resources under your organization only,
   "owner" role is enough. But if you need to control folder and organization itself too, "owner" + "organization administrator" role is necessary.

Comment: Owner + Organization Administrator is not enough to manage **everything**. Many permissions are only contained in specific roles. There is no single role that has all permissions.

Comment: @JohnHanley Yes, owner + organization role can't manage ALL resources in Google Cloud. ex : Billing account.. But if "resource" means VMs, buckets, etc.. This role enough. isn't it?

Comment: No, those roles are not enough. Owner is a legacy role. The organization Administrator does not have a lot of permissions. Create a list of all GCP permissions. Then list the permissions of both roles.